# Meteor - templates. Building simple catalogue

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I am Meteor newbie, so please, don't blame me too much for stupid question! I am fairly trying to find answer in Google and Meteor.docs, but my foolishness is stronger than me at now.

I am trying to build simple Catalog of Products from two Collection.

```
Catalogs = new Mongo.collection('catalogs');
Products = new Mongo.collection('products');
```

My target - is to achieve view like this:

```
Vegetables     <-- #1 catalog
  *Tomato      <-- product from #1 catalog
  *Cucumber    <-- another product from #1 ctalog
Fruits         <-- #2 catalog
  *Apple
  *Pineapple
  *Banana
```

I have no problem with creating catalogs and adding products to them with parent ID's. But now I'm stuck with Meteor templates and have no ideas, how to show products, that nested in their parents catalogs. 
Sometime I do similar thing with Laravel, and in that case I check for each product with Laravel's Blade like this:

```
{{$catalog->name}}
    @foreach ($products as $product)
       @if ($catalog->id == $product->parentId)
         {{$product->name}}
       @endif
    @endforeach
```

I agree, maybe it's not elegant solution, but it works for me. 
But in Meteor, with changing "data contexts" (if I understand their role right), I cannot grasp, how to do this thing, if I can't get parent or child properties. I believe that it must have clear and straight way of solving, but I can't see it by myself :(

Please, can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each catalog has a `name` and each product has a `name` and a `catalogId`, here's a template which shows all catalogs and products as a series of lists:

```html
<template name='catalogProducts'>
  {{#each catalogs}}
    <div class='catalog-name'>{{name}}</div>
    <ul>
      {{#each products}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.catalogProducts.helpers({
  catalogs: function() {
    // find all of the catalogs
    return Catalogs.find();
  },
  products: function() {
    // here the context is a catalog, so this._id is the id
    // of the current catalog - this finds all of its products
    return Products.find({catalogId: this._id});
  }
});
```

Recommended reading: [A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)

Comment: Thank you very much, David! Very useful link. Promise you, I won't make so stupid mistake again :)

Comment: It's all part of the learning process. :) I'm glad that was helpful.